# responsive design - how to make the images look normal on small screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on this test page:
http://problemio.com/index_test.php

It looks ok on my laptop screen. But it looks terrible on my phone browser. Especially the images look like a mess.

What can be done to make sure the images look ok?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You need to add some code and/or a jsfiddle so that when this link changes, this question still has historical value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media queries to style elements for mobile devices. With images use percentages along with max-width and min-width values too.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    //CSS sizes for mobiles only
}
```

Comment: thank you. I am a bit confused about the media elements. Do all modern browsers just recognize them? Or do I have to import some css library?

Comment: IE7 and below don't support media queries

Comment: @CodyGuldner thank you - so if I create a few of the same named media elements, how will the older browsers know which element to choose?

Comment: All mobile devices support media queries and they are the only ones that need to support them too as it's the sole purpose of their presence. Older desktop browsers should not concern you as regards media queries as they will not be the targeted market. Media queries are used in addition to basic CSS. Older browsers will be using you standard CSS and mobiles will use both.

Comment: Would anyone know the difference between twitter bootstrap and polyfill? Which should I use?

Comment: Use bootstrap, it's well documented and ideal for a first timer.

Answer (score 3):

[Omega](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981217/1470950) has the right idea, but you want to set the `width` parameter as well. I usually set the `width` to a percentage value, and `max-width` to a pixel value. That way, once it has gotten past the max width, it essentially throws that aside, and only looks at the width. Something along the lines of this

```
img {
  max-width:500px; /*Once screen size is smaller than 500px, the image reverts to the width value*/
  width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XUHa/)

Comment: Thanks for the mention. I might be missing your point though. You're saying if the image is more than 500px then it'll fall back to the width attribute which is 100%? Surely just using `max-width:100%` will do the same? By default images will display at their natural size unless specified elsewhere.

Comment: @Omega `max-width:100%` would ensure that the image would never cross browser width lines. You could use this, but if you have a 1700px screen with an image that is supposed to be a 250x250 image, then this image will be very stretched out and distorted. So I do it this way so the image won't stetch out

Comment: Hence why you use height:auto and not set any other measurement attributes for the image. It will only stretch and distort if you specify it's measurement to do so. Otherwise the maximum it will display is it's natural size... No?

Comment: Height auto will do nothing. It means the browser will calculate the height

Comment: Okay lets forget about height auto for now, what about my question above though? Just exploring different views here, to see if I can learn something new by the way..

Comment: I believe I answered it in my first comment, unless there is something else you are confused about

Answer (score 1):

Don't set pixel messurements for your images and use this css instead for img tags:

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```